# Getting CORS error When Using Spotify Open APIs

Tags: angularjs, angular, spotify

I'm getting CORS error while trying to get some data through Spotify's Open APIs such as `API/v1/search?type=album&q=...` and `API/v1/albums/{id}` in a Simple Angular 4 Application that searches for albums with a Query then tries to show that specific album Information.

I assume that these two APIs are open and don't need any kind of authorization. So How can I get data from these two when there's no JSONP method available without getting CORS error and without Authorization?

Passing `client_id` doesn't help I'm afraid.

Comment: If you get a CORS error, the the API is probably not supposed to be used this way. You can work around by routing requests to this API through your own server. Only the browser checks CORS response headers, calls from a server ignore them.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the reply and I know it can be worked around but It's weird! I found a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/JMPerez/0u0v7e1b/) by Jose Manuel Perez who's Spotify Maintainer which shows how Search API works. I use the exact same API to search for albums the exact same way! The Fiddle works but my Single Page Application Doesn't and it's weird to me! I guess I'm Missing something here! I can Implement Implicit Grant Flow but I don't want to! I shouldn't have any kind of Authorization! :(

Comment: Perhaps you're sending some additional headers that cause CORS to kick in.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Nothing that can cause that! I double checked! Here's my application if it helps: http://masoudmirzaei.ir/coverfinder

Comment: Most likely you are using an `http` origin to access an `https` API.

Comment: @georgeawg I didn't think of that one! Maybe that's the problem! 
I can't use an SSL so I'm writing a Wrapper for the API anyway! thanks for mentioning and your reply though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one posted a proper answer, I ended up writing and using a simple wrapper over Spotify's API. Everything's working now! No more darn CORS errors or anything! :)